# smtp-request behind iptables-router not working

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, smtp, router, ip-forwarding

I set up a router with ip-forwarding on Ubuntu 16.04 Server edition.
I enabled ip-forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf .
I have set

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and executed

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

I used the following iptables commands:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${PRV_IF} -s ${PRV_NET} -o ${PUB_IF} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${PUB_IF} -d ${PRV_NET} -o ${PRV_IF} -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o ${PUB_IF} -j MASQUERADE
```

I have a different local linux machine behind the router in the ${PRV_NET} from that I want to access server-ports like 22, 25, 80, etc in the internet, e.g. let us say on myserver.com

E.g. accessing Ports 22 and 80 on myserver.com from my local machine works

```
telnet myserver.com 22 ... works
telnet myserver.com 80 ... works
```

However I cannot access a mail server on myserver.com from the local machine:

```
telnet myserver.com 25 ... hangs up
```

The last command hangs up and never returns.

How can I access mail servers from the local network?
Are there any mistakes in the iptables-commands?

Comment: Where are these machines located? Who are the Internet service providers?

Comment: How do you know the connection "hangs up"? In SMTP it is not unusual for the server to not send a banner, so it may be waiting for you; or maybe that service is not open on myserver.com. Suggest running tcpdump ("tcpdump -nnv tcp port 25") on your local Linux machine to see whether or not you are getting a SYN-ACK, or perhaps a RST, from myserver.com when you try the telnet on port 25.

Comment: Location is Germany, Provider Hetzner

Comment: The mail-service is running, I have access to the mail-server. Besides, I can access port 25 via telnet from the router. I am sorry I am not familiar with tcpdump, I will have a look at that and post information.